# How to GET/POST a ressource with OAuth 2.0 in JAVA (Status Code 415)

Tags: java, rest, api, http, shopware

i have a implementation for oauth 2.0 in Java, i wanted to try out some things with the Shopware 6 API. I can get the access token without problems and, as far as i see, i'm doing everything right to request a ressource with this access_token. In the header for the GET Request i put the 'Authorization Bearer' + access_token header and also the "Content-Type", "application/json" header.

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(resourceURL);
        get.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

and later

```
if (isValid(accessToken)) {
                        // update the access token
                        // System.out.println("New access token: " + accessToken);
                        oauthDetails.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                        // remove the old auth header
                        get.removeHeaders(OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION);
                        // add the new auth header
                        get.addHeader(OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION,
                                getAuthorizationHeaderForAccessToken(oauthDetails.getAccessToken()));
                        get.releaseConnection();
                        response = client.execute(get);
                        code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

The Error Code i always get is 415. 
This is the complete response:

`HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type [Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2019 08:45:38 GMT, Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian), Cache-Control: no-cache, private, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE, Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,sw-context-token,sw-access-key,sw-language-id,sw-version-id, sw-version-id: , sw-language-id: , sw-context-token: , x-frame-options: deny, X-Debug-Token: c1766c, X-Debug-Token-Link: http://localhost:8000/_profiler/c1766c, X-Robots-Tag: noindex, Vary: Authorization, Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100, Connection: Keep-Alive, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Content-Type: application/json] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Chunked: true]}}`

The endpoint im trying to get is the "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/category/" endpoint. If im doing this whole thing with Insomnia/Postman i get the expected category information.
Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? What am i missing here?

Comment: Can you add an 'Accept': 'application/json', header and try again?

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you... don't know how i could overread that in the dokumentation, i only read "application/json" and thought, yeah yeah, got that, but i only had it for the Content-type set and not the Accept header...

Comment: ok I am writing as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add following header

```
'Accept': 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

As nuriselcuk pointed out in the comment, the missing thing was the Accept header.
I added

```
post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

and now its working fine.